# Search Engine with Multiple Qualification Filters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, multi-query

I am trying to build a search engine like the ones Job portals have. My query is particularly related to qualification. My end user may query for employees who have a single or set of qualification-discipline combinations, or they may give a list of qualifications with disciplines and ask for all employees who have done any of the given qualification-discipline combinations. My script is as follows.

```
declare @Qualification table(QualId int identity primary key, Qualification varchar(100))
declare @Discipline table(DispId int identity primary key, Discipline varchar(100))
declare @Emp table(Eid int identity primary key, EName varchar(100))
declare @EmpQualification table(Eid int, QualId int, DispId int)
declare @ReqData table(QualId int, DispId varchar(100))
declare @AllMandatory char(1)

insert into @Qualification
select 'Diploma' union
select 'B.E' union
Select 'MBA' union
select 'MCA' union
Select 'B.Sc' union
Select 'B.Com'

insert into @Discipline
select 'HR' union
select 'IT' union
Select 'Computers' union
select 'Agriculture' union
Select 'Civil'

insert into @Emp
select 'SANTHOSHANAND M' union
select 'VENKATA VEERA JAGADEESH MANNE' union
select 'E.SURESH KUMAR' union
select 'E HARIHARA PUTHIRAN' union
select 'SOUMYAJIT MOHANTY' union
select 'TANMOY DAS' union
select 'PANAKANTI SANTHOSH' union
select 'G NAVEEN KUMAR' union
select 'VIJAY LOGANATHAN' union
select 'SAI KIRAN GANDHE'

INSERT INTO @EmpQualification
SELECT 1,1,3 UNION
SELECT 1,5,4 UNION
SELECT 2,2,2 UNION
SELECT 2,6,3 UNION
SELECT 3,3,3 UNION
SELECT 3,2,3 UNION
SELECT 4,4,2 UNION
SELECT 4,2,3 UNION
SELECT 5,5,4 UNION
SELECT 5,3,1 UNION
SELECT 6,6,3 UNION
SELECT 6,4,3 UNION
SELECT 7,1,3 UNION
SELECT 7,5,5 UNION
SELECT 8,2,3 UNION
SELECT 8,6,3 UNION
SELECT 9,3,1 UNION
SELECT 9,1,3 UNION
SELECT 10,4,5 UNION
SELECT 10,2,5 

SELECT e.Eid, E.EName Name, ql.Qualification, d.Discipline FROM @Emp E
INNER JOIN @EmpQualification Q ON E.Eid = Q.Eid
INNER JOIN @Qualification QL ON Q.QualId = QL.QualId
INNER JOIN @Discipline D ON Q.DispId = D.DispId

insert into @ReqData
select 1,'Any' union
select 5,4

set @AllMandatory = 'N'

if @AllMandatory = 'N'
select * from @Emp where Eid in (
select distinct q.Eid from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId, convert(int,DispId) DispId from @ReqData where DispId <> 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId and q.DispId = f.DispId
union
select distinct q.Eid from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId from @ReqData where DispId = 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId)
--else
-- My recursive procedure goes here, which consumes lot of time
```

Sample query of my users is as follows.

[image]

This will come in my `@ReqData` table as below

[image]

All employees who meet all the mentioned criteria. This is captured through my `@AllMandatory` variable

```
set @AllMandatory = 'Y'
```

The above query should give me all the employees who did B.Com with any discipline and also did their MBA in HR. Following should be the query result

```
Eid EName
1   E HARIHARA PUTHIRAN
```

Assume that with the same `@ReqData` table, if `@AllMandatory` is set to `N`, the result should be as follows, which means all employees who have done either B.Com with any discipline or all employees who have done MBA HR.

```
Eid EName
1   E HARIHARA PUTHIRAN
5   SAI KIRAN GANDHE
7   SOUMYAJIT MOHANTY
9   VENKATA VEERA JAGADEESH MANNE
```

`@ReqData` may sometimes come with 50 to 60 rows.
To achieve this I am only able to do with looping or stored procedure recursion. I have around 50000 employees and around 2,00,000 qualifications which keep growing too. So, this looping and recursion are making my system slow. Is there a better and easier way to solve this? Is it actually possible to handle it with a single query?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server has supported the `VALUES` clause for inserts since 2008 (maybe even 2005). There's no need to those expensive `UNION` (or less expensive `UNION ALL`) queries anymore.

Comment: "Sample query of my users is as follows".  The example is a result set, not a query.  I'm confused.

Comment: My end-users select the required qualifications and disciplines in front-end, the image which I posted is actually how they see, how it comes in SQL server is what my `@ReqData` table has.

Comment: You have 20 000 000 000 qualifications? Please don't use Indian words like "lakh". We're not all from India

Comment: Yaa, my mistake, corrected in question

Comment: See [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) by the great Joe Celko

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to achieve this without looping or recursion. Posting the solution below. Thank you all for the help.

```
declare @Qualification table(QualId int identity primary key, Qualification varchar(100))
declare @Discipline table(DispId int identity primary key, Discipline varchar(100))
declare @Emp table(Eid int identity primary key, EName varchar(100))
declare @EmpQualification table(Eid int, QualId int, DispId int)
declare @ReqData table(QualId int, DispId varchar(100))
declare @AllMandatory char(1)
declare @CriteriaCnt int

insert into @Qualification
select 'Diploma' union
select 'B.E' union
Select 'MBA' union
select 'MCA' union
Select 'B.Sc' union
Select 'B.Com'

insert into @Discipline
select 'HR' union
select 'IT' union
Select 'Computers' union
select 'Agriculture' union
Select 'Civil'

insert into @Emp
select 'SANTHOSHANAND M' union
select 'VENKATA VEERA JAGADEESH MANNE' union
select 'E.SURESH KUMAR' union
select 'E HARIHARA PUTHIRAN' union
select 'SOUMYAJIT MOHANTY' union
select 'TANMOY DAS' union
select 'PANAKANTI SANTHOSH' union
select 'G NAVEEN KUMAR' union
select 'VIJAY LOGANATHAN' union
select 'SAI KIRAN GANDHE'

INSERT INTO @EmpQualification
SELECT 1,1,3 UNION
SELECT 1,5,4 UNION
SELECT 2,2,2 UNION
SELECT 2,6,3 UNION
SELECT 3,3,3 UNION
SELECT 3,2,3 UNION
SELECT 4,4,2 UNION
SELECT 4,2,3 UNION
SELECT 5,5,4 UNION
SELECT 5,3,1 UNION
SELECT 6,6,3 UNION
SELECT 6,4,3 UNION
SELECT 7,1,3 UNION
SELECT 7,5,5 UNION
SELECT 8,2,3 UNION
SELECT 8,6,3 UNION
SELECT 9,3,1 UNION
SELECT 9,1,3 UNION
SELECT 10,4,5 UNION
SELECT 10,2,5 

SELECT e.Eid, E.EName Name, ql.Qualification, d.Discipline FROM @Emp E
INNER JOIN @EmpQualification Q ON E.Eid = Q.Eid
INNER JOIN @Qualification QL ON Q.QualId = QL.QualId
INNER JOIN @Discipline D ON Q.DispId = D.DispId

insert into @ReqData
select 2,2 union
select 6,3

select @CriteriaCnt = count(QualId) from @ReqData

set @AllMandatory = 'N'

if @AllMandatory = 'N'
select * from @Emp where Eid in (
select distinct q.Eid from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId, convert(int,DispId) DispId from @ReqData where DispId <> 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId and q.DispId = f.DispId
union
select distinct q.Eid from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId from @ReqData where DispId = 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId)
else
begin
select em.* from @Emp em
inner join
(select h.Eid, count(h.QualId) Cnt from 
(select distinct q.Eid, f.QualId from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId, convert(int,DispId) DispId from @ReqData where DispId <> 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId and q.DispId = f.DispId
union
select distinct q.Eid, f.QualId from @EmpQualification q
inner join (select distinct QualId from @ReqData where DispId = 'Any') f on q.QualId = f.QualId) h
group by h.Eid
having count(h.QualId) >= @CriteriaCnt) m on m.Eid = em.Eid
end
```